# On safari, my canvas cursor animation work as black screen

Tags: javascript, canvas, safari, html5-canvas

I have a site on tilda, that has canvas with glitch animation, but it didnt work on safari,it show the black screen, whats the problem?

try to setTimeout to delay the download of canvas, but it work only 5 of 10 times

code:

```
if ($(window).width() > 768) {
 const imgSize = [1650, 1000];

const vertex = `
                attribute vec2 uv;
                attribute vec2 position;
                varying vec2 vUv;
                void main() {
                        vUv = uv;
                        gl_Position = vec4(position, 0, 1);
                }
        `;
const fragment = `
                precision highp float;
                precision highp int;
                uniform sampler2D tWater;
                uniform sampler2D tFlow;
                uniform float uTime;
                varying vec2 vUv;
                uniform vec4 res;

                void main() {

                        // R and G values are velocity in the x and y direction
                        // B value is the velocity length
                        vec3 flow = texture2D(tFlow, vUv).rgb;

                        vec2 uv = .5 * gl_FragCoord.xy / res.xy ;
                        vec2 myUV = (uv - vec2(0.5))*res.zw + vec2(0.5);
                        myUV -= flow.xy * (0.15 * 0.7);

                        vec2 myUV2 = (uv - vec2(0.5))*res.zw + vec2(0.5);
                        myUV2 -= flow.xy * (0.125 * 0.7);

                        vec2 myUV3 = (uv - vec2(0.5))*res.zw + vec2(0.5);
                        myUV3 -= flow.xy * (0.10 * 0.7);

                        vec3 tex = texture2D(tWater, myUV).rgb;
                        vec3 tex2 = texture2D(tWater, myUV2).rgb;
                        vec3 tex3 = texture2D(tWater, myUV3).rgb;

          gl_FragColor = vec4(tex.r, tex2.g, tex3.b, 1.0);
                }
        `;
{
  const renderer = new ogl.Renderer({ dpr: 2 });
  const gl = renderer.gl;
  $(gl.canvas).appendTo('#mouse-deformation');
  //document.body.appendChild(gl.canvas);

  // Variable inputs to control flowmap
  let aspect = 1;
  const mouse = new ogl.Vec2(-1);
  const velocity = new ogl.Vec2();
  function resize() {
    let a1, a2;
    var imageAspect = imgSize[1] / imgSize[0];
    if (window.innerHeight / window.innerWidth < imageAspect) {
      a1 = 1;
      a2 = window.innerHeight / window.innerWidth / imageAspect;
    } else {
      a1 = (window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight) * imageAspect;
      a2 = 1;
    }
    mesh.program.uniforms.res.value = new ogl.Vec4(
      window.innerWidth,
      window.innerHeight,
      a1,
      a2
    );

    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
    aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
  }
  const flowmap = new ogl.Flowmap(gl, {
    falloff: 1.0, // size of the stamp, percentage of the size
    alpha: 0.3, // opacity of the stamp
    dissipation: 0.94 // affects the speed that the stamp fades. Closer to 1 is slower
  });
  // Triangle that includes -1 to 1 range for 'position', and 0 to 1 range for 'uv'.
  const geometry = new ogl.Geometry(gl, {
    position: {
      size: 2,
      data: new Float32Array([-1, -1, 3, -1, -1, 3])
    },
    uv: { size: 2, data: new Float32Array([0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 2]) }
  });
  const texture = new ogl.Texture(gl, {
    minFilter: gl.LINEAR,
    magFilter: gl.LINEAR
  });
  const img = new Image();
 
       img.onload=()=>(texture.image = img);
  img.crossOrigin = "Anonymous";
  
  img.src = "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/064wgjmnq6m49ca/глитч%20фон.jpg?dl=1";
 

  let a1, a2;
  var imageAspect = imgSize[1] / imgSize[0];
  if (window.innerHeight / window.innerWidth < imageAspect) {
    a1 = 1;
    a2 = window.innerHeight / window.innerWidth / imageAspect;
  } else {
    a1 = (window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight) * imageAspect;
    a2 = 1;
  }

  const program = new ogl.Program(gl, {
    vertex,
    fragment,
    uniforms: {
      uTime: { value: 0 },
      tWater: { value: texture },
      res: {
        value: new ogl.Vec4(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight, a1, a2)
      },
      img: { value: new ogl.Vec2(imgSize[0], imgSize[1]) },
      // Note that the uniform is applied without using an object and value property
      // This is because the class alternates this texture between two render targets
      // and updates the value property after each render.
      tFlow: flowmap.uniform
    }
  });
  const mesh = new ogl.Mesh(gl, { geometry, program });

  window.addEventListener("resize", resize, false);
  resize();

  // Create handlers to get mouse position and velocity
  const isTouchCapable = "ontouchstart" in window;
  if (isTouchCapable) {
    window.addEventListener("touchstart", updateMouse, false);
    window.addEventListener("touchmove", updateMouse, { passive: false });
  } else {
    window.addEventListener("mousemove", updateMouse, false);
  }
  let lastTime;
  const lastMouse = new ogl.Vec2();
  function updateMouse(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (e.changedTouches && e.changedTouches.length) {
      e.x = e.changedTouches[0].pageX;
      e.y = e.changedTouches[0].pageY;
    }
    if (e.x === undefined) {
      e.x = e.pageX;
      e.y = e.pageY;
    }
    // Get mouse value in 0 to 1 range, with y flipped
    mouse.set(e.x / gl.renderer.width, 1.0 - e.y / gl.renderer.height);
    // Calculate velocity
    if (!lastTime) {
      // First frame
      lastTime = performance.now();
      lastMouse.set(e.x, e.y);
    }

    const deltaX = e.x - lastMouse.x;
    const deltaY = e.y - lastMouse.y;

    lastMouse.set(e.x, e.y);

    let time = performance.now();

    // Avoid dividing by 0
    let delta = Math.max(10.4, time - lastTime);
    lastTime = time;
    velocity.x = deltaX / delta;
    velocity.y = deltaY / delta;
    // Flag update to prevent hanging velocity values when not moving
    velocity.needsUpdate = true;
  }
  requestAnimationFrame(update);
  function update(t) {
    requestAnimationFrame(update);
    // Reset velocity when mouse not moving
    if (!velocity.needsUpdate) {
      mouse.set(-1);
      velocity.set(0);
    }
    velocity.needsUpdate = false;
    // Update flowmap inputs
    flowmap.aspect = aspect;
    flowmap.mouse.copy(mouse);
    // Ease velocity input, slower when fading out
    flowmap.velocity.lerp(velocity, velocity.len ? 0.15 : 0.1);
    flowmap.update();
    program.uniforms.uTime.value = t * 0.01;
    renderer.render({ scene: mesh });
  }
}
```

please help

Comment: https://woodwood.agency/888